# Can I use a state that refers to the states of one child in another child component?

Tags: reactjs

Because of the architecture of the application I'm working on, I need to have access to the states of one child component in another child component and I can't take these states to the parent or use react-redux. So I use a technique where I store pointers to the states of the target child in the parent.
In parent I create state for pointers:

```
export default function App() {
const [compOneStatePointers, setCompOneStatePointers] = useState({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CompOne setCompOneStatePointers={setCompOneStatePointers}></CompOne>
      <CompTwo compOneStatePointers={compOneStatePointers}></CompTwo>
    </div>
```

In CompOne I create state and save pointer for this state in parent's 'compOneStatePointers' state.

```
    const [state, setState] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        setCompOneStatePointers((prev) => {
          const temp = { ...prev };
          temp.state = state;
          temp.setState = setState;
          return temp;
       });
    }, [setCompOneStatePointers, state]);
```

After that I can use state from CompOne in CompTwo. Like this:

```
    <button className="button" onClick={() => {
        props.compOneStatePointers.setState(prev=> prev+1)
    }}>Change state of Comp One</button>
```

Example of this technique: https://codesandbox.io/s/state-pointers-object-62dkl?file=/src/CompTwo.js
The question is, can I do this or are there pitfalls?

Comment: Thank you for the remark. The question has been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of Context API in react js which provides a way to pass data to all the components(called Component Tree) in your react application without passing the props deep to all the levels of component explicitly.

You can read the same concept from the official Documentation of Reactjs https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context.

From production perspective, it would be better to use Context API for passing date from one component to one on more component. In real life react application, there would be 100 or more components, and using the context they will interact.

Comment: I think concept of Context API work fine with mutable data, for example language of UI or color theme. Like this: <SomeContext.Provider value="ConstData"> This data remains unchanged from the start of the application to its exit. But in my case, every time then user press to image preview app get new image data.  And I don't know if the context can be used in the case of variable data.

Answer (score 0):

When you keep your app architecture as simple as this, I would say, you have a good approach there. Nothing wrong with passing setState and state to different components from a parent.

Once you get a little more complex, I recommend using something structured like Redux or somehting more native and flexible like rx-global (its only 13kb large) or build your own state management library (like rx-global is).